# Any ideas for a sorted array that is easily indexed by key value range?

Tags: ios, arrays, sorting

Scenaro: iOS/Objective-C application.  I have anywhere from a few dozen to a few thousand entries that I must collect and place in order by timestamp.  That much is easy -- NSArray sorted by descriptor.

However, I will need to be able to access the array and select multiple entries by time range (where the start/end times may not correspond exactly to any entry).  And this is modestly performance sensitive, both for setup time and for access time.

Best I can come up with is to sort the array and do a binary search for start/end points.  This is certainly doable and probably sufficiently fast.  However, it doesn't quite "feel" right (though I can't articulate why).

Any other ideas?

Comment: If performance is the key for this issue maybe you should use Core Foundation.

Comment: @JuanCatalan - Could you be a bit more specific?  "Core Foundation" is basically just the "CF" side of Cocoa.  (If you meant "Core Data", it would likely be slower, plus we can't use it due to data security concerns.)

Comment: I mean using CFArray instead of NSArray and C functions to perform your logic instead of Objective C methods. If you can't bare using NSPredicate for performance and plan to do a binary search, you should optimize for performance and not for simplicity in the code. My answer was to offer a simple code to do it, not an optimal performance code.

Comment: @HotLicks: Is the array created once and searched frequently, or does it change between searches? Are the start/end points for the searches arbitrary timestamps or "discrete", e.g. only searches for a range of days?

Comment: It's kind of a mixed bag.  It's created and likely searched dozens of times.  But there may be several arrays created without searching, if the user is flipping rapidly between months.  Haven't figured out the final pattern yet -- depends on how much I want to cache, etc.

Answer (score 1):

1) Sort the array (optional, but you said you needed)

2) Instead of binary search, use NSPredicate to find the entries you are interested in.

Here is a sample code from one of my projects that you have to adapt to your own class, the one that has the timestamp.

```
// this is the property wher you store the data
@property NSArray *data;

// this is a custom struct to hold to timestamp values, the min and max 
typedef struct CMTTimeStampRange {
  UInt64 min, max;
} CMTTimeStampRange;

// return a sub array with only the objects between two time stamps
- (NSArray *)samplesInTimeStampRange:(CMTTimeStampRange)timeStampRange
{
  NSArray *tsRange = @[@(timeStampRange.min), @(timeStampRange.max)];
  NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"timeStamp BETWEEN %@",tsRange];
  NSArray *samples = [self.data filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
  return samples;
}
```

**Update**

This snippet above is intended to offer a simple solution to the question posted, not intended to be a high performance code. For high performance i'd suggest using Core Foundation (CFArray) and C functions. CFArray has a function CFArrayBSearchValues that is binary search in a sorted CFArray, so you don't have to do your own function.

Comment: But I have relatively little confidence that NSPredicate will take advantage of sort order and do as well as a binary search.

Comment: I prefer to use the API instead of coding a method to do binary search. It is up to you of course. If you do the test I'll be interested in knowing the performance. Recall also that you'll have to do two binary searches, one for the maximum and one for the minimum.

Comment: Actually, knowing that one must search for both it is probably possible to optimize the search and use some of the failed probes from the first to "prime" the second.  Hmmm....

Comment: By the way the method with NSPredicate doesn't need a sorted array